# Internal links not working for me in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I've looked around a bit and everything is telling me that `[link](path)` should create link markup. I however cannot get it to work for some reason.

I originally tried `[my link]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link _my_collection/my-file.md %})` and it just prints out `[my link](my/correct/path)`, but is not creating the markup. I also tried `[link text](https://google.com)` with the same result. Does anyone know what I could be missing, perhaps some gem?

Using jekyll 3.7.2

Comment: What is the extension of your file?

Comment: .md just like my second example

Comment: okay.. will need a public link to your repository to see if there's something else at play (e.g, config settings, plugins, front matter, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using your markdown inside [html block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements (p, h1, ...). And kramdown, by default, doesn't parse markdown in such tags.

In order to parse md inside html block elements, you can configure kramdown like this :

**_config.yml**

```
kramdown:
  parse_block_html: true
```

Comment: I was hopeful about this one but it did not work. I saw another post that had the same reason which suggested adding markdown="1" on the block element. That didn't work either though. Nor did combining the fixes.

Comment: The repository is private. I can try to work up a public one that is similar when I have time. I would imagine you just need the **_config.yml** and maybe **package.json** / **Gemfile**, right?

Comment: and an .md page reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten this about this question. It does not appear that there is any way that Jekyll can translate this markup directly but I did manage a workaround with the `markdown` text filter:

```
{%- capture links -%}
  [my link]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link _my_collection/my-file.md %})
  [my link](my/correct/path)
  [link text](https://google.com)
{%- endcapture -%}
{# Remove <p> tags that markdownify seems to add #}
{{ links | markdownify | remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling into issues with rendering links in markdown files between Liquid blocks, don't indent the tag expression!

```
{% for post in site.posts %}}
    <a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Produces: `<a href="post-url">post-title</a>`

Whereas

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
<a href="{{post.url}}>{{post.title}}</a>"
{% endfor %}
```

Produces a working link!